# When does docker copy files into a volume at runtime?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to understand when containers copy preexisting files into a mounted volume on the same directory. For example

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN mkdir /testdir 
RUN echo "Hello world" > /testdir/file.txt
```

running:

```
#docker create volume vol
#docker run -dit -v vol:/testdir myimage
#docker exec -it 900444b7ab86 ls -la /testdir
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 11 18:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 May 11 18:43 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6 May 11 17:53 file.txt
```

The image for example also has files in:

```
# docker exec -it 900444b7ab86 ls -la /etc/cron.daily
total 20

    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 26 21:17 .
    drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 May 11 18:43 ..
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1478 Apr 20 10:08 apt-compat
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1176 Nov  2  2017 dpkg
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  249 Jan 25 15:09 passwd
```

But for example when I run it with

```
docker run -it 900444b7ab81 -v vol:/etc/cron.daily
```

The directory is now empty..

Why don't the files get copied this time?

Comment: it seems that no cron job ran yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
#docker run -dit -v vol:/testdir
```

That is not a valid docker command, there's no image reference included, so there's nothing for docker to run.

```
docker run -it 900444b7ab81 -v vol:/etc/cron.daily
```

This will attempt to run the image `900444b7ab81` with the command `-v vol:/etc/cron.daily`. Before you had a container id with a very similar id, so it's not clear that you aren't trying to do a run with a container id instead of an image id. And the command `-v` likely doesn't exist inside the container.

The order of these arguments is important, the first thing after the `run` that isn't an option or arg to the previous option is treated as the image reference. After that reference, anything else passed is a command to run in the container. So if you wanted to mount the volume, you need to move that option before the image id.

> I'm trying to understand when containers copy preexisting files into a mounted volume on the same directory.

With named volumes, docker initializes an empty named volume upon creation of the container with the contents of the image at that location. Once the volume has files in it, it will be mapped as is into the container on any subsequent usage, so changes to the image at the same location will not be seen.